# Terraform - dependency between modules

Tags: terraform

I'm trying tell terraform the resource is dependent on other one. The problem is the resources are in separate modules. The dependent resource looks like that:

```
variable dependency {
  type = "list"
  default = []
}

resource "docker_container" "web" {
  depends_on = "${var.dependency}"
...
```

Then I 'call' the module:

```
module "wordpress" {
  source = "../modules/wordpress"
  dependency = [ "${module.provision.res}" ]
}
```

And I got error:

```
  on ../modules/wordpress/main.tf line 11, in resource "docker_container" "web":
  11:   depends_on = "${var.dependency}"

A static list expression is required.
```

It looks like I cannot use variable in 'depends_on'. How to create dependency between modules?

PS: The resource I depend on is a null_resource which provides some some provisioning. I need to rebuild some stuff every time it changes.

Comment: Not sure you can depend on a variable. Perhaps this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14056) would help.

Comment: `depends_on` is used for dependencies between resources that are not implicitly generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve the error: "A static list expression is required."

You need to wrap the var.dependency with []:

```
resource "docker_container" "web" {
  depends_on = ["${var.dependency}"]
...
```

Update: The syntax above is for **terraform<0.12**. 
For **terraform >=0.12**, as @Maciej Wawrzyńczuk points out, **[var.dependency]** will just work in this case. **["${var.dependency}"]** will also work in 0.12 as backward compatibility but if you run tf 0.12 you probably want to do it the new way.

Comment: Almost. "depends_on = [ var.dependency ]" works fine. :)